# 2 GFCI connected

Tags: electrical, gfci

I had 2 parallel GFCI outlets installed in the kitchen
(Each one is on a separate fuse to the main box).
The Green lights are on solid..but every, now and then... maybe 10 seconds or so, the Red light Blinks once. Is that some kind of issue?

Comment: What make and model are your GFCIs?

Comment: That may be a built-in test function. If something is plugged in, does it blink when the red light blinks?

Comment: The Brand name is TR (Made in China) It was the only one I could find at my hardware store. I took a quick video but I don't see a way to post it here. Thanks for the quick replies. I'm impressed.

Comment: "TR" means it's a **T**amper **R**esistant outlet - it's not the brand name.

Comment: That's too funny. Then it has no Brand name.. Only "Made in China" Also red light blinks even with something plugged in.

Comment: If it doesn't have a UL listing (or at least CSA or ETL), you can't use it at all.  And the hardware store could be in big trouble with the FTC for selling it over the counter.  If your hardware store is amazon.com, all bets are off lol (Amazon is "only a platform to connect buyers to sellers" so they say).